# In .NET/C# world, do you need to (over)use interfaces due to limitation of language, framework, library? (question coming from Java dev)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface

**Before you'll downvote, let me explain**

It's not another question about reason to use interfaces. I hope I know most important reasons to use them and I do use interfaces in Java code I write.

I have just seen a coding practice that seems to be very frequent overuse of interfaces. **But I don't have C# background and maybe I misjudge some necessary practice.** On contrary, if it's a bad practice, I would like to confront it as a reviewer (scroll below if you're curious why Java dev reviews C# code).

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for any viable reasons to create interfaces that would appear useless from perspective of good practice in general, but would be a popular practice caused by some limitation of C#, library or framework.

**Questions**

Does C# (.NET Framework 4.5) or most preferred libraries somehow enforce practice of creating interfaces for practically all classes?

Is Rhino Mocks a preferred library for mocking? Maybe there are better alternatives?

**Example of code in question: Interface created for simple data carrier that is practically a tuple**

```
namespace Blah.Mlah.Requests
{
    internal interface IUserInfoRequest
    {
        IRequestId RequestId { get; }
        string UserName { get; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Blah.Mlah.Requests.RequestsImplementation
{
    internal class UserInfoRequest : IUserInfoRequest
    {
        public UserInfoRequest(IRequestId requestId, string userName)
        {
            RequestId = requestId;
            UserName = userName;
        }
    }
    
    public IRequestId RequestId { get; }
    
    public string UserName { get; }
}
```

**Example of code in question: Interface created for class that is container of constants**

```
namespace Blah.Mlah.Requests.Constants
{
    internal interface IRequestConstants
    {
        string SomeConstantName { get; }
        string OtherConstantName { get; }
        // and 10 more of such definitions
    }
}
```

```
namespace Blah.Mlah.Requests.Constants
{
    internal class RequestConstants : IRequestConstants
    {
        public string SomeConstantName => "ConstantValue";
        public string OtherConstantName => "AnotherConstantValue";
        // and 10 more of such constants
    }
}
```

**More on observed coding practice**

Majority of interfaces (similar to examples above) I see in recently reviewed C# code are annoying white noise, being one more unnecessary step while navigating through code, unnecessary source file to skim through during review (in hope that this one is really useful). They are rather useless from perspective of principles behind using interfaces in general (I describe my view on those principles on bottom).

Even extremely simple data object needs an interface according to author of classes in question (having C++ background). Even old, existing classes gain their interfaces recently. For old, heavy classes there are heavy interfaces added in recent commits. Maybe that's my personal opinion, but interface - that outlines spaghetti of methods - doesn't make an improvement. I don't need interface to strenghten that spaghetti as a contract. And I have outline with methods in modern IDE. Classes with dozen(s) of methods rather need a refactor into many smaller classes, each with single responsibility. Then you don't even need outline if you have a small class that fits on one screen.

Such frequent addition of interfaces is justified by mentioned developer as general C# coding practice and also requirement of **Rhino Mocks** (which is apparently unable to mock a class - it needs an interface to create a mock). Separate question is why would anybody mock a class with no methods and two fields. Such method is simply a carrier of small amount of data and in most (if not all) cases can be directly used in tests.

**Background - if you're curious why Java dev reviews C# code**

I am Java developer evolving/maintaining old data server project that was created with client libraries written in both Java and C#. We are (hopefully temporarily) understaffed and I recently participate in code reviews of C# code. My presence is mostly required from perspective of Java and C# libraries meeting same standards and contracts from business perspective, but I also try to catch up and do a proper review with some knowledge of C# and used frameworks.

**My example reasons to use interfaces - if you're worried that I'm one of guys who don't get idea of using interfaces**

Obviously I use interfaces in Java code, but I use them when I sense some value in such addition, for example:

- When there is a need to specify some contract for public use, for example in public API of our libraries,
- When it is good to decouple business logic from code dependent on currently used library/technology that can be replaced with another one in future (for example data store),
- When it generally helps to decouple separate components/domains,
- When same action is performed in many ways or in many contexts, so it's better to create several classes extending an interface instead of making one behemoth with huge sets of switch cases for each method,
- To create a 'skeleton' for some patterns, for example chain of responsibility.

In many cases it is obvious that some class will never become anything that would require an interface.

Regards,
Peter.

Comment: Adding an interface to everything is plainly wrong.  Your final bullet points are just as valid in C# as Java.  Mocking does require an interface.  Moq is another very populator mocking library.  First 2 classes seem reasonable, interface of constants is pointless.

Comment: Sounds like whoever wrote the code you're reviewing is just doing it wrong. Interfaces certainly have their place and are incredibly useful but, like in any other language feature, should be used where appropriate. Using an interface for what is basically a struct makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation in the framework or the language. In theory, if you translate your Java code into C#, it will work the same.

The overuse of interfaces that you mention are most likely due to inexperienced developers or limitations of third-party libraries, such as the one that you mention.

Here are the links to the [C# interface Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) and [Programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/).